# Certain navigation elements show hover when on page, others dont?

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

A client of mine is having a strange problem with their sites navigation.. on certain pages their hover class appears to show what page you're currently viewing. But on others it doesn't?

I didn't design this site, but I'm helping them work on it, so I'm a tad bit lost.

http://www.hycroft.com/

The suites and policies don't show when you're currently on them, but the rest do.. if anyone has any insight I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hover image is set in your menu css here,

```
#nav li:hover, #nav li.sfhover,
body.index #nav li.index,
body.amenities #nav li.amenities,
body.concierge #nav li.concierge,
body.suites #nav li.suites,
body.specials #nav li.specials,
body.reservations #nav li.reservations,
body.location #nav li.location,
body.contact #nav li.contact {
    background-position: 0 -63px
}
```

So when you are on the home page, the body tag has a index class added to it. It seems a different name is applied for pages where it does not show.

Comment: Andrew is right.. in the policies page for ex if you rename the body class to index then your missing arrow appears, so the problem is menu.css. The menu have been changes but somebody forgot the css

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the style for the current page navigation item are controlled by a class on the `body` element. Adding the "suites" class to the body causes the pointer to show for it. The "reservations" class gets the policies menu item to do it.

Those classes aren't being applied to the `body` element for those pages. (Different classes are being applied, actually)

Answer (score 1):

On the Suites page:

```
#nav li:hover, #nav li.sfhover, body.index #nav li.index, body.amenities #nav li.amenities, body.concierge #nav li.concierge, body.suites #nav li.suites, body.specials #nav li.specials, body.reservations #nav li.reservations, body.location #nav li.location, body.contact #nav li.contact {
    background-position: 0 -63px;
}
```

Clearly the body class determines the highlighted menu, but on the suites page,

`<body class="monaco">`